# How to align legend symbol with wrapped legend text on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, figure

Is there a way to align the legend symbol (red, green or blue dot) with the first line of the wrapped legend text on this example plot? (taken from eipi10 [Multiple Lines for Text per Legend Label in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062532/multiple-lines-for-text-per-legend-label-in-ggplot2))

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

# Create long labels to be wrapped
iris$Species = paste(iris$Species, 
                     "random text to make the labels much much longer than the original labels")

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, colour=str_wrap(Species,20))) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(colour="Long title shortened\nwith wrapping") +
  theme(legend.key.height=unit(2, "cm"))
```

[image: Plot with wrapped legend text]

It's a point of detail but a coauthor insisted on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one solution that is sort of a hack by changing the background color to white and using vjust. I couldn't find an easy way to top-align the point within the box...

```r
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)
# Create long labels to be wrapped
iris$Species = paste(iris$Species, 
                     "random text to make the labels much much longer than the original labels")

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, colour=str_wrap(Species,20))) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(colour="Long title shortened\nwith wrapping") +
    theme(legend.key.height=unit(2, "cm"), legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(label.vjust = -1, label.position = "right"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>