# Align long legend titles in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a diagram generated as follows:

```
gplot(aggregate(cbind(Tax_Burden,debt_GDP) ~ cou, data=df, mean, na.rm=TRUE), aes(x=log(debt_GDP), y=log(Tax_Burden))) +
  #geom_text(aes(label=cou), size=2) +  
  geom_point(aes(color = Tax_Burden, size=debt_GDP))+  
  labs(color = "Tax Burden [% Total Revenues]", size = "Public Debt [% GDP]")+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, linetype="dashed")+
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = cou), size = 2)+
  ylab("Log of Tax Burden") +
  xlab("Log of Public Debt [% GDP]") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.key   = element_blank(),
        legend.text  = element_text(size = 6),
        legend.title=element_text(size=6),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8))
```

My problem is that in one of the legends `color` its title is too long [I align legends to the right]. How should I modify my options in the theme to account for that long title ?

for instance how I can split the long tile `Tax Burden [% Total Revenues]` into two rows ?

Comment: please try: `color = "Tax Burden\n[% Total Revenues]"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062532/multiple-lines-for-text-per-legend-label-in-ggplot2