# Multiple Fixed Lines for Text per Legend Label in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

(This question expands on [Multiple Lines for Text per Legend Label in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062532/multiple-lines-for-text-per-legend-label-in-ggplot2).)

I need to include multiple lines of information in legend labels. These labels need to be broken into lines at fixes points, which is why the solution in the previous example doesn't work for me. I've tried using `\n`, but in the expression I'm using, I end up with an offset.

```
set.seed(10)
dat_sof<-tibble(x=seq(1:10))%>%
            mutate(y=x+rnorm(10))

leg_col<-c("S1"="blue", "S2"='black')
leg_lty<-c("S1"=1, "S2"=2)
leg_lab<-c(expression("S1:\n y = m1 x + b1\n"~ R^{2} ~ " = r1, n = n1"), 
           expression("S2:\n y = m2 x + b2\n"~ R^{2} ~ " = r2, n = n2"))

ggplot(data=dat_sof, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method='lm', aes(color="S1", lty="S1"), se=F)+
  geom_abline(aes(color="S2", lty="S2", slope=1, intercept=0.1))+
  theme_bw(base_size=14)+
  scale_color_manual(values=leg_col, name="Regressions", labels=leg_lab)+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=leg_lty, name="Regressions", labels=leg_lab)+
  theme(legend.text.align = 0)
```

What I end up with is the third line being off-set from the rest of the alignment, and the legend not being properly spaced.
[image: totally unreadable legend]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ggtext` and use `element_markdown()` in your `theme` which gives you a lot of flexibility:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(10)
dat_sof<-tibble(x=seq(1:10))%>%
  mutate(y=x+rnorm(10))

leg_col<-c("S1"="blue", "S2"='black')
leg_lty<-c("S1"=1, "S2"=2)
leg_lab <- c("S1:<br>y = m1x + b1<br>R<sup>2</sup> = r1, n = n1",
             "S1:<br>y = m2x + b2<br>R<sup>2</sup> = r2, n = n2")
ggplot(data=dat_sof, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method='lm', aes(color="S1", lty="S1"), se=F)+
  geom_abline(aes(color="S2", lty="S2", slope=1, intercept=0.1))+
  theme_bw(base_size=14)+
  scale_color_manual(values=leg_col, name="Regressions", labels=leg_lab)+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=leg_lty, name="Regressions", labels=leg_lab)+
  theme(legend.text.align = 0,
        legend.text = ggtext::element_markdown(),
        legend.key.height=unit(2, "cm"))
```

[image]