ggarange: graphs with different size legend
I am trying to group three different graphs using ggarrange.
The graphs are exactly the same, but the legend on the bottom graph is too long. Therefore, I am getting the following figure:

I tried to include to theme(legend.box = "horizontal") in the graph code and use the following for the ggarrange:
ggarrange(plot_sex, plot_ethnicity, plot_disability + 
          rremove("x.text"), 
          labels =  c("A", "B", "C"),
          ncol = 1, nrow = 3,
          legend = "right",
          widths = c(1, 1, 5),
          align = "v")

I want the graphs on the right to be aligned. Can someone help me?
Thank you!

what if you move the legend of each plot below the plot instead of keeping it on the right? or what if you split the text of the long legend into multiple rows, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47062532/multiple-lines-for-text-per-legend-label-in-ggplot2? Maybe you can even reduce the text of the labels of the long legend?
also, it would help to have a reproducible example of the plots you are trying to arrange.

I prefer patchwork over ggarrange in part because of issues like this. For a patchwork approach, try saving each of your 6 figures as p1, p2, p3, etc.. then when you are ready to stitch the figures together you can use p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + plot_layout(nrow = 3)

Here is a patchwork solution.
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

# Create plots individually
p1 <- mpg %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cty, y = hwy, color = manufacturer)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = 'none')

p2 <- mpg %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cty, y = hwy, color = manufacturer)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = NULL) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        legend.justification = 'left') +  # To left align the top legend
  guides(color = guide_legend(ncol = 2))

p3 <- mpg %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cty, y = hwy, color = model)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')

p4 <- mpg %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cty, y = hwy, color = model)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(y = NULL) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(ncol = 3))

# Stitch the individual plots together (will look better on your local machine)
p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + plot_layout(ncol = 2)


Created on 2024-06-27 with reprex v2.1.0
